# An adjective to describe a substance consisting of smaller-size grains

Tags: word-choice, adjectives, comparatives

What adjective you would use to describe a substance consisting of grains of smaller size compared to those of another substance? For example, "Milk powder is ***_*____**_er than sugar".

Addition:

And if it's possible, please, come up with an antonym of that word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I would simply use "**finer**"

> "Milk powder is finer than sugar".

Those different articles ("[How Particle Size and Shape is Defined](http://www.skylighter.com/fireworks/how-to/Measure-particle-size.asp)", "[Powder Manufacturing Methods](http://www.btinternet.com/~catechnology/surfaceweb/swebjournalspage_files/powders.htm)", "[forum on Imperial sugar](http://forum.cakecentral.com/modules.php?name=Forums&file=viewtopic&p=330717&sid=deb784974cfc6a0df6800f7c79ef37d7#330717)", ...) all uses that adjective.

A possible antonym would be "larger", but in this context, a more precise one would be "**[grainier](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grainy)**" or rather (thanks to [Robusto](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/2303/robusto); see the comments):
"**[coarser](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/coarse?show=0&t=1291567432)**" (composed of relatively large parts or particles).

Comment: Thank you VonC for your answer and for these links. Can you please also come up with an adjective opposite to "finer".

Comment: @brilliant: just edited my answer to include possible antonyms.

Comment: +1: Finer is the correct word. I would suggest "coarser" as an antonym, however.

Comment: @Robusto: thank you. I have included it in the answer.

Answer (score 6):

> Milk powder is **finer** than granulated sugar but **coarser** than icing sugar.